# How do I create an A record in a hosted zone with the AWS node SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I am using the Route 53 Node API to create and configure a hosted zone. Creating the zone works fine, but when I try to use the changeResourceRecordSets function to add an A record, I get an error that says 'InvalidInput: Invalid request' but doesn't say what is invalid about it. Here is my request params object:

```
var zoneConfig = {
  ChangeBatch: {
    Changes: [{
      Action: 'CREATE',
      ResourceRecordSet: {
        Name: 'my.domain.com',
        Type: 'A',
        Region: 'us-east-1',
        TTL: 300,
        ResourceRecords: [{
          Value: '111.222.111.000'
        }]
      }
    }],
    Comment: 'direct hosted zone A record to point to the server'
  },
  HostedZoneId: 'ZZH1GLJKE22DK'
};

rt53.changeResourceRecordSets( zoneConfig, function(...
```

Any ideas what might be wrong in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  The problem was the `Region` field in the `ResourceRecordSet`.  I missed it in the documentation, but that is only to be used for latency-based resource record sets.  So, deleting that line fixed the issue

Really wish the API error message could have just said that.